# Validate user input to only accept type int or String "quit"

Tags: java, validation, input, user-input

My code prints out an array which is already declared then asks for user input. User is supposed to enter a number in the format xy or type quit to stop using the program. After getting user input it prints out the element of the array using x as row and y as column number which is followed by setting that index to 0 and printing the new array.
I have so far achieved most of it apart from accepting only integers or "quit" from the user. If user enters another string apart from "quit" the program crashes.
This is my code.
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Exercise23 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [][] array = {
            {0, 1, 4, 5},
            {3, 7, 9, 7},
            {1, 8, 2, 1}
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        boolean exitCon = false;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number in the format 'xy' with no spaces in between or enter 'quit' to stop");
            String xy = read.nextLine();
            if (!"quit".equals(xy)) {
                String x = xy.substring(0, 1);
                String y = xy.substring(1);
                int row = Integer.parseInt(x);
                int column = Integer.parseInt(y);
                if (0 <= row && 0 <= column && row <= 2 && column <=) {
                System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(array[row][column]);
                    array[row][column] = 0;

                    System.out.println();

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                            System.out.print(array[i][j]);
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                } else { System.out.println("The number has to be in range 00-23 inclusive considering the format 'xy'.");

                }

            } else if (xy.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("You can only enter integers or 'quit'.");               
            } else {
                exitCon= true;   
            }

        } while (!exitCon);

    }
}
```

The problem is in this bit

```
String xy = read.nextLine();
if (!"quit".equals(xy)) {
    String x = xy.substring(0, 1);
    String y = xy.substring(1);
    int row = Integer.parseInt(x);
    int column = Integer.parseInt(y);
    if (0 <= row && 0 <= column && row <= 2 && column <= 3) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(array[row][column]);
        array[row][column] = 0;

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        } else { System.out.println("The number has to be in range 00-23 inclusive considering the format 'xy'.");

        }

    } else if (xy.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("You can only enter integers or 'quit'.");               
    } else {
        exitCon= true;
```

I get this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at Exercise23.main(Exercise23.java:26)
"

Comment: What error do you get when it crashes?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the error message. Edited now. @Steve101

Comment: That means your input string (`next.readLine()`) has length equal zero. So then `xy.substring(0, 1)` throws Exception

Comment: I think that was because I tried an empty string. When I enter something else it crashes again

Comment: Yes, there are a few points when do something without checking for right input. Before parsing the string you have to check if it is entered correctly. Length is the first check, other one wold be to check if contains only digits.

Comment: Don't alter you question, because the old one has been answered. Create a new question instead.

Comment: I just changed the error message because the previous one was when I returned a blank line. My problem is when a string apart from quit is entered. Sorry @Tom

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you have to create a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the code, this will cover the cases and is simple extendable:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,"UTF-8"));
        String s;
        while ((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
            if (s.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            else if (s.matches("\\d{2}")) {
                // parse it (exactly 2 digits)
                System.out.print("parse:"+s);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You can only enter 2dig integers or 'quit'.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the exception added, it appears the failure is occurring here;

```
String x = xy.substring(0, 1);
String y = xy.substring(1);
```

The StringIndexOutOfBoundsException means the String "xy" is too short, presumably blank on the readline.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that any string that is not "quit" will enter the first if condition, this is what causes your code to crash. You only want to enter the fist condition if the string supplied is numeric. What your conditions should be are:

```
if (StringUtils.isNumeric(xy)) {
...
} else if (!xy.equals("quit")) {
    System.out.println("You can only enter integers or 'quit'.");
} else {
    exitCon= true;
}
```

Comment: I get error message "cannot find symbol ". when using StringUtils.

Comment: @UysalM `StringUtils.isNumeric()` is from the Apache Commons Lang library and which is a third party library you'd have to import. I was just using it as an example of what the logic should be (since `.isNumeric(xy)` is very self explanatory). The important part is to check if the string is a number, whether it'd be using a third party library or regex matching or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I have managed to solve my own problems with ideas from your answers and comments.

I made these changes

```
if (xy.length() == 2) {
    String x = xy.substring(0, 1);
    String y = xy.substring(1);
    int row = Integer.parseInt(x);
    int column = Integer.parseInt(y);
    if (0 <= row && 0 <= column && row <= 2 && column <= 3) {
    System.out.println();
        System.out.println(array[row][column]);
        array[row][column] = 0;

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(array[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        } else { System.out.println("The number has to be in range 00-23 inclusive considering the format 'xy'.");

        }

} else if ("quit".equals(xy)) {
        exitCon= true;                              
} else {
        System.out.println("You can only enter integers or 'quit'.");
```

Comment: Your solution is still "wrong". Consider entering two chars which are not digits. That is why you should check input very precisely.

Comment: How can i check that it only contains digits after checking its length. After all it can contain characters in order for string quit to work. @krzydyn

Comment: see my answer please